# Conditionally keeping the latest copy of a row with ON CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql, upsert

Postgres 13.4.

I got a request today to build what amounts to a conditional `ON CONFLICT` statement. The idea is that we get readings from various instruments that provide a timestamp. This is an approximation of our situation, we might be using a timestamp or version number. Either way, the value is built outside of Postgres. We trust that external timestamp or version number. However, readings can come in out-of-order, and we always want to keep the latest one. So, regardless of `INSERT` sequence, the latest copy is kept. I have a solution working in a toy test, and I'm wondering if I'm missing a better strategy, or what I've got listed below has holes I don't expect.

For the toy test, a simple table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reading;

CREATE TABLE reading (
    instrument_number  int4       NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    reading_dts        timestamp  NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    note               text       NOT NULL DEFAULt ''
);

INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (1, '2022-01-15 15:30:45', 'Red');

select note from reading where instrument_number = 1 -- Red
```

What we're usually doing is shown below. Namely, use an `ON CONFLICT` on a PK or `UNIQUE` constraint to favor the incoming record, regardless of its contents.

```
-- Duplicate key error, as expected:
INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (1, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Blue');

select note from reading where instrument_number = 1 -- Red

-- Resolves PK conflict:
INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (1, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Blue')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT reading_pkey
         DO UPDATE SET reading_dts = EXCLUDED.reading_dts,
                              note = EXCLUDED.note;
                              
select note from reading where instrument_number = 1 -- Blue
```

The new wrinkle is that we want to keep the copy of the row with the latest `reading_dts` value. But there's no `if` logic in SQL like that. I noticed in the docs that `ON CONFLICT` supports a `WHERE` clause, and it *seems* to work:

```
-- INSERT Earlier then Later: Later wins. 
INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (2, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Earlier')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT reading_pkey
         DO UPDATE SET reading_dts = EXCLUDED.reading_dts,
                              note = EXCLUDED.note
      WHERE EXCLUDED.reading_dts > reading.reading_dts;
      
   select note from reading where instrument_number = 2 -- Later
         
INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (2, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Later')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT reading_pkey
         DO UPDATE SET reading_dts = EXCLUDED.reading_dts,
                              note = EXCLUDED.note
      WHERE EXCLUDED.reading_dts > reading.reading_dts;
                                    
select note from reading where instrument_number = 2 -- Later

DELETE from reading WHERE instrument_number = 2;
  
-- INSERT Later then Earlier: Later wins. 

INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (2, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Later')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT reading_pkey
         DO UPDATE SET reading_dts = EXCLUDED.reading_dts,
                              note = EXCLUDED.note
      WHERE EXCLUDED.reading_dts > reading.reading_dts;

select note from reading where instrument_number = 2 -- Later

INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (2, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Earlier')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT reading_pkey
         DO UPDATE SET reading_dts = EXCLUDED.reading_dts,
                              note = EXCLUDED.note
      WHERE EXCLUDED.reading_dts > reading.reading_dts;

select note from reading where instrument_number = 2 -- Later
```

One thing that makes me a bit wary here is that I had to add `reading.` to qualify the reference to the *existing* record. Here's what happens otherwise:

```
INSERT INTO reading (instrument_number, reading_dts, note)
     VALUES (2, '2022-01-15 15:30:45','Later')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT reading_pkey
         DO UPDATE SET reading_dts = EXCLUDED.reading_dts,
                              note = EXCLUDED.note
      WHERE EXCLUDED.reading_dts > reading_dts;
      
ERROR:  column reference "reading_dts" is ambiguous
LINE 6:       WHERE EXCLUDED.reading_dts > reading_dts;
```

I didn't find a name for `THIS.`, or whatever, in the docs and tried the table's name. It *seemed* to work. But, I don't want to build a plan on top of that.

Any advice or additional information appreciated.

Comment: Looked through the `INSERT` documentation again, and the examples at the bottom do show referencing the target table by name or alias. So, it seems that the `reading.reading_dts` syntax is legit.